# C Prints One Char More Without Value

Tags: c, input, char, printf, scanf

I am trying to print the ASCII values of 3 char-type characters. When I input the first char it doesn't print the value of the char. After the first char it starts to give the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  {
    char ch;
    int t;
    while(t < 3){
        scanf("%c\n", &ch);
        printf("%c - %d\n", ch,ch);
        t++;
    }
}
```

http://i54.tinypic.com/2mdqb7d.png

Comment: It might be a good idea to initialize `t`...

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c",&ch);` that will skip all white spaces.

Comment: changed t to t=0 but still same. i use gcc to compile code.

Comment: If I were you, I would try flushing stdout after calling printf.

Answer (score 2):

Variable t is not automatically initialized to 0 by compiler. So You need to initialize t with 0. If printf doesn't print immediately it means the data is buffered. If you want to see immediatley you may consider flushing stdout right after printf.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this several times, and don't know the root cause, but solution that works is:

scanf("\n%c", &ch);

It probably has something to do with buffered end of line character.